Meta API to get "call for action" while creating ads
I am using python sdk facebook_bussiness for acceissng meta apis. So when we create ad we have to choose the call to action depending on the type of media uploaded if media is an image then CTA would be differnet and diffirent for Videos.
My questions is there any endpoint/function in the sdk which return me the CTAs depending on the media type, so that I don't have to hardcore values in code.
